# bootstrap table display different between GoogleChrome and Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I am using bootstrap table to display my data, and it work fine on Google Chrome, but cannot work fine on Firefox.

This is what i saw on **google chrome**.[image: Google Chrome]
This is what i saw on **firefox**.
[image: firefox]

this is my code

```
echo<<<EOF
  <div class="x_content">
     <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style='font-size:13px;'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr height="10">
                                            <th class="col-sm-1">#</th>
                                            <th class="col-sm-8">Leave Category</th>
                                            <th>Is Active </th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                     <tbody>

EOF;
$this->fetch(); //this is the function to get data from database
echo<<<EOF
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
EOF;
```

javasript

```
<script>

        var asInitVals = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        'bSortable': false,
                        'aTargets': [0]
                    } //disables sorting for column one
        ],
                'iDisplayLength': 12,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });
            $("tfoot input").keyup(function () {
                /* Filter on the column based on the index of this element's parent <th> */
                oTable.fnFilter(this.value, $("tfoot th").index($(this).parent()));
            });
            $("tfoot input").each(function (i) {
                asInitVals[i] = this.value;
            });
            $("tfoot input").focus(function () {
                if (this.className == "search_init") {
                    this.className = "";
                    this.value = "";
                }
            });
            $("tfoot input").blur(function (i) {
                if (this.value == "") {
                    this.className = "search_init";
                    this.value = asInitVals[$("tfoot input").index(this)];
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How do I change the css to work fine on both?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you construct the html with php. You'd rather show us the whole html code generated, since it is hard to find out an HTML error by looking just an extract of it.

Comment: @Amarnasan if i remove the javascript part, the layout will look fine

Comment: We still need to see the finished HTML code.

Comment: @Epodax I found out the problem already, once i add ` "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip','` and it will work fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has it's dependencies when using the built-in grid.

```
<div class="container"> <!-- It can be either container or container-fluid -->
 <div class="row"> <!-- Similar to the upper one -->
  <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- col-xs-*, col-md-*, col-lg-* -->
   ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Check the Bootstrap docs, especially the grid: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)